# How do I find out the sea levels?

Tags: dem, elevation, hydrology

I have following elevation data of a region (the higher the altitude, the brigher the points):

[image: Elevation]

How can I find out, which areas are filled by water, and which not?

Can I assume that if the elevation is below X meters, the place is filled with water? If yes, what is X equal to?

Comment: In truth, you can't determine this from just a DEM.  You can infer flat spots, but sometimes interpolation will hide them, too.  What ancillary data do you have?

Comment: What data sets (apart from *SRTM Water Body Dataset*) can I use to infer sea levels?

Comment: consider the Netherlands for why just filling areas below 0 with water will not work

Comment: There is a large set of possible sources, but only what you have can be used.  There are complex issues of scale at play, as well, which make this an entire question unto itself (quite a bit better than the current state of this one, to be honest).  I recommend that you edit this question to focus on vector data, but you'll also have to be a great deal more specific about your area of interest, and why the water body data is not more than sufficient.

Comment: you can pour water on it

Comment: @Adam has a good idea--but the method is not entirely straightforward.  Starting with a point where you know the sea is (and which therefore should have an elevation of zero or less in the DEM), you can incrementally flood the DEM by slowly raising the sea level up to zero. The technique is described and illustrated at http://www.quantdec.com/SYSEN597/studies/flood .

Comment: @whuber Thanks. I'm looking for some easy-to-implement method, which works in 80 % of the cases. I don't need precision because I need this to create a map for a game (nobody will die, if there are a couple of watering errors in the map).

Answer (score 3):

Your main question title indicates you're looking at sea level and coastal areas. But we'll start at the bottom of your question and work backward.

Consider lakes and rivers. Many of them may be significantly above sea level, even their bottoms, thus relying on elevation alone in the DEM cannot tell you if an area is water or not. Plus in a DEM large water surfaces generally appear as flat at the surface elevation. Expanding on this, and what iant alludes to, there are many places with inland areas that are *below* sea level (or theoretical zero in your DEM) that are *not* covered by water.

As Vince says, scale and resolution of the DEM are also a factor and basically you need ancillary data - elevation alone can't tell you. Imagery, maps, and vector data of coastlines are possible sources. Hydrology tools could also be potentially used in that they can fill 'up' and account for some of those isolated low areas not being covered until a certain elevation is reached at which point it spills in from surrounding areas. If you look up examples of studying sea level rise you'll find numerous examples of how just going up or down from zero doesn't quite work.